# Vertical Fixed and fluid layout with no browser scrollbar

Tags: html, css

[image]

I wanted my page to have a behavior like in the image.
The 100% box has the height of the browser screen and the auto box has a min-height, let's say 100px, so, what I like is to the auto box to increase/decrease and if its height is lower than 100px, then create the scroll bar IN the auto box and NOT the browser (as in the image).

**EDIT:** http://jsfiddle.net/erwingo/gMEBn/
The problem is that when you resize down the windows, the scroll bar appears because the --div class="content"-- doesn't seem to decrease.

Sorry if my english is not good enough.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far please.

Comment: I post this image in dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5st78ccx88tawo/box.jpg

Comment: Hi Erwin, sorry I meant please show us what code you have written so far so that the SA community can try and help you with it.

Comment: I edited the post with the url with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the height of the elements in percentages of the screen. Then give your content area `overflow: auto;`

Another option, since the heights on your headers and footer seem to be static is to set the content to be `position:absolute; top: totalOfHeadersHeight; bottom: footerHeight; overflow: auto;` It will then give you the content area as filling the screen with it's own separate scroll area.

Comment: But I can't determine what the "remaining" area is in order to set to --div class="content"-- an specific height.
The main div (container) in the example, can decrease/increase between 100px and 150px. I updated the jsfiddle Look at it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works as expected! I updated the jsfiddle for anyone who wants to know how I solved this, of course with your help.